# Series Parallel Circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

I want to be more conceptual so I am not going to discuss the specific values of each resisitor. I cannot seem to find online how to find the equivalent resistance of this circuit. I first thought of adding R1 and R3, but there is R2 in between. I then thought of adding R1 and R2, which I think may be right. But this would mean I would only use the series circuit equation for resistance addition when I should be using the parallel circuit equation somehow. Basically, I am not sure how to combine these resistors to find the equivalent resistance.

Comment: Take your finger and 'push' R1 to the left, around the corner, and halfway down the left most wire.  Now, isn't it clear that R1 and R2 are parallel connected?

Comment: I did not know that you can change the position of resistors in the schematic. Well, technically, you're not I guess I mean appearance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you start studying circuits, it can be as simple as how the circuit is drawn. In this case, it may not be obvious that R1 and R2 are in parallel. Redrawing in a way that "looks" more natural to you often helps.

Then you take steps to reduce the circuit. Replace R2 with the calculated vales of R1 and R2. Now you have a simple series circuit.

In the U.S. there is ALWAYS one of these on the AP Physics exam, but more complicated.